# Maven error: Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven

I have the following problem in a maven project in both eclipse and netbeans

```
    Failed to execute goal on project ui: 
    Could not resolve dependencies for project <<package>>:ui:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), 
    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    cglib:cglib:jar:2.2 (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.18 (compile), gr.imu.ntua.tweetinspire:services:jar:1.0 (compile), 
    org.cloudfoundry.samples:tomcat7-standalone:tar.gz:7.0.29 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), 
    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1 (compile), 
    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test), 
    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (test), org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.cloudfoundry.samples:tomcat7-standalone:tar.gz:7.0.29: Could not transfer artifact org.cloudfoundry.samples:tomcat7-standalone:pom:7.0.29 from/to jets3t (http://www.jets3t.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://www.jets3t.org/maven2/org/cloudfoundry/samples/tomcat7-standalone/7.0.29/tomcat7-standalone-7.0.29.pom, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden
```

while my pom.xml file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <groupId>gr.imu.ntua.tweetinspire</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </parent>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
        <name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Freemarker -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.18</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.cloudfoundry.samples</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-standalone</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.29</version>
                <type>tar.gz</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>package-inside-tomcat7</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>attached</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/assembly/tomcat7.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <finalName>tomcat7</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>tomcat7-standalone-repo</id>
                <url>http://ericbottard.github.com/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

    </project>
```

I have deleted the repos and build again but the problem remains.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is you are having the wrong credentials for the repository  `...(http://www.jets3t.org/maven2): Access denied to: http://www.jets3t.org/maven2/org/...`

Apart from that the repository does not look like Maven repository.

And also the `http://ericbottard.github.com/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7` gives a page not found which gives me the impression this is not a valid repository.

Furthermore i would suggest first to use Maven Central only which means no repository entries in your pom.xml files which is the wrong way at all.

Just check if it works without the repository definition. If you really need to define other repository better use a repository manager (Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva).

One other thing is that i see in your pom the version which is a released versions already in contradiction beeing not ready with development. So the best would be to use a SNAPSHOT version which is intended for development.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your answer helped me to solve my problem. It was about the credentials that I had not provided correctly.